# Matlab - Request data every minute and and retrieve data from JSON using Matlab

Tags: json, matlab

I am trying to extract the "EUR/USD" price from this site: https://www.stockpair.com/trading

I used HTML-parsers before but realized that dynamically generated content is not retrieved using this method.

I checked the console to see how the site updates the data and found that it sends "POST" request URLs generating the information in JSON-Format (see for example: https://www.stockpair.com/tapi2/update?o=1599910&tsc=1423500801963&json). So I suppose I can simply use this URL and adjust the "tsc" attribute to get the JSON encoded data.

Now I am wondering how I can request this URL with Matlab and send that request every minute and then retrieve data from the returned JSON-Object using matlab. Also, how could I ensure that the new request automatically adjusts the "tsc" attribute to account for the additional minute?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply delete the `tsc` parameter if you want data for "now". For a json parser check matlab file exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that leaving the `tsc` provides the data for "now"!